# How can I let the output return True or False based on the input of the list?

Tags: python, list, function, tuples

So I have a list `hand` whose data is something like this `['AS', 'AD', 'AC', 'CH', 'CS']`. Now I have to find the **first character of each element in the list** and see if there are **3 identical letters** and **2 identical letters or not**.

**Note**: **they must all be in order though.. like always x,x,x,y,y or y,y,x,x,x. Any other combination, like x,y,y,x,x or x,y,x,y,x, will return False**

So for example

`['AS', 'AD', 'AC', 'CH', 'CS']` returns `True` because there are 3 A and 2 C.

`['AS', 'SD', 'SC', 'CH', 'CS']` returns `False` because the order is not right

`['CS', 'CD', 'AC', 'AH', 'AS']` returns `True` because there are 3 A and 2 C

`['AS', 'CD', 'DC', 'AH', 'CS']` returns `False` because none of the characters appear 3 times and 2 times.

Here is my code so far, which doesn't work...

```
hand = ['AS', 'AD', 'AC', 'CH', 'CS']
updated_hands = list([x[1] for x in hand])
if ((updated_hands[0] == updated_hands[1] == updated_hands[2]) or (updated_hands[2] == updated_hands[3] == updated_hands[4])) and ((updated_hands[3] == updated_hands[4]) or (updated_hands[0] == updated_hands[1])):
    print('True')
else:
    print('False')
```

What changes should I make to this?

Comment: Why doesn't it work?

Comment: The first character is `x[0]`, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is something that should work for arbitrary lengths and orders:

```
hands = [['AS', 'AD', 'AC', 'CH', 'CS']]
hands.append(['AS', 'SD', 'SC', 'CH', 'CS'])
hands.append(['CS', 'CD', 'AC', 'AH', 'AS'])
hands.append(['AS', 'CD', 'DC', 'AH', 'CS'])

for hand in hands:

    condition = True

    last_count = 1
    last_item = hand.pop(0)[0]

    while hand:
        item = hand.pop(0)

        if (item[0] == last_item):
            last_count += 1 

        if (last_item != item[0]):
            if (last_count == 2) or (last_count == 3):
                condition = True
            else:
                condition = False
                break

        last_item = item[0]

    print(condition)
```

Outputs:

```
True
False
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the approach I would take, which is effectively the same as what you've tried but I've just expanded it a bit to try and make it more readable.  I think probably what you've got is "correct", but the complexity of doing it as a one liner is hiding a small bug.

```py
def test_list(hand):
    test1 = all(let[0] == hand[0][0] for let in hand[:3])
    test2 = all(let[0] == hand[0][0] for let in hand[:2])
    test3 = all(let[0] == hand[2][0] for let in hand[2:])
    test4 = all(let[0] == hand[3][0] for let in hand[3:])
    
    if (test1 and test3) or (test2 and test4):
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")

hand1 = ['AS', 'AD', 'AC', 'CH', 'CS']
hand2 = ['AS', 'SD', 'SC', 'CH', 'CS']
hand3 = ['CS', 'CD', 'AC', 'AH', 'AS']
hand4 = ['AS', 'CD', 'DC', 'AH', 'CS']

test_list(hand1) #prints True
test_list(hand2) #prints False
test_list(hand3) #prints True
test_list(hand4) #prints True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Lets Make it Simple.

    hand = ['AS', 'AD', 'AC', 'CH', 'CS']
    a = [sorted(han[0][0]) for han in hand] 
    
    import itertools
    b = itertools.chain(*a)
    c = list(b)
    
    d = [han[0][0] for han in hand] 
    
    if c == d:
    print(True)
    else:
    print(False)
=======================================================================
You Can Get Any List From user.
```

[You Can Get List From User](https://pynative.com/python-accept-list-input-from-user/)